# Will My Laptop Get Damaged If I Leave It Turned On In A Laptop Bag Inside A Car?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I am going on a vacation tomorrow and my destination is four hours away!

I want to bring my laptop with me by putting it in a laptop bag and putting it in the trunk!

I do not want to shut down my computer and I am afraid what will happen if I leave it on!

Should I leave it on or should I turn it off?

Comment: Why wouldn't you at least put it to sleep, that's what the feature is for, those question isn't logical

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you should turn it off. If you don't it will likely overheat and, at best, shut itself off. It may shut itself off without doing a proper OS shutdown. It may overheat enough to cause damage before it shuts down.

Put it in hibernate (not just sleep) if you don't want to lose your state.

Answer (score 0):

You have not advised why you don't wish to shut it off, but leaving it on in a bag in the trunk is not a great idea. The 2 main challenges this poses are the heat buildup and potential hard drive damage.

If you have an SSD you don't need to worry about drive damage as it does not have spinning parts, so it's not going to be damaged by inertia and head knocks. If you do, you want to stop all disk activity, park the heads (easier said then done) and put it as close to the center of the car as the trunk allows.

As far as heat buildup goes, kill as many processed as possible so the CPU does not need to work, which will minimize heat.

If you can put the PC into sleep - or better, hibernate mode, it will solve these issues.